# purchase orders are processed in grid table view but in of detail order it shows completed in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid, purchase-order

I am using magento 1.9.In history some entries are looks processing but in details of this purchase order it is completed.All entries are from last year. How may I get resolution for this.

Comment: Did you update the order status using some custom code? And can you please check "sales_flat_order_grid" table?

Comment: NO dint add any custom code..sales_flat_order_grid dont have acess to database.